# Cannot return value from `if __name__ == "__main__"` in a Python script?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to collect output of a Python script in a bash script where the Python script is called like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

outputString=$(./test.py 2>&1)
echo $outputString
```

But it looks like I cannot return from the block `if __name__ == "__main__"` ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def my_method():
    return 'somethng'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    value = my_method()
    return value
```

Running `test.sh` complains the following error:

```
File "./test.py", line 11 return value SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot return from inside `if __name__ == "__main__"` ?

Comment: Of *course* you can't. You can only return from a function. Note, there *is no main method in your script*. Python has no notion of a "main method", in any case.

Comment: You said "it looks like I cannot return from my main method". Where is your main method?

Comment: You want to *output to the standard output device*. Normally, that is done with the `print` function in Python

Comment: Is there no way I can return from within `if __name__ == "__main__"` ? Only way is to directly call the Python method?

Comment: You already wrote you want to collect **output** which is different. You can use "print" or "sys.stdout.write" for this.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer what you are saying doesn't make sense. *You can only return from functions*. `if __name__ == "__main__"` is not a function, it is a normal if-statement. It is used to allow your script to be used as both a module and an importable script. It isn't' actually necessary, but in any case, returning from it is nonsensical. What you seem to want here *is to print to the standard output device*

Comment: I got your point about `if __name__ == "__main__"` and updated my question to not called it `main`. But then there is no way to return a value from `if __name__ == "__main__"`. What if I my script accepts a parameter and based on that I am supposed to return a value from my Python script?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer what do you mean by returning a value from your script? How are you going to use that value?

Comment: you already have `value = my_method()`.  Value is the return "value" from `my_method()`. I am not sure what's so confusing about this.  If `my_method` took a parameter: `my_method(num)` and you want to return `num` you would do that inside `my_method` itself

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer I've explained to you already multiple times. Please take a moment to actually read what several people are telling you. **You need to print to standard out**, i.e. by using the `print` function. You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding on how these things work.

Comment: Ah I need to print to standard output. Got it. Sorry for being slow

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer The only "value" you can return from a script is the errorlevel number. Everything else must be transferred by output stream, socket, temporary file or more obscure ways.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch

Comment: @MichaelButscher you should just write that up as an answer, I suspect many people will land on this with basically the same question.

Comment: Yes. Please make an answer using `Print`. Its simple once you understand but this is not obvious in Python by the way.

Comment: Nice! It works using `Print` :-D

Comment: What if there are multiple Prints done from the same Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the exit value from python (or any other program) like this

```
#!/bin/bash

./test.py 2>&1
echo $?
```

you can exit with a value different than 0 if ther's an error

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def my_method():
    return 'somethng'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(my_method())
    sys.exit(0)
```